# Create a Tree-ExpandableListView for a recursive folder structure in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need to create an ExpandableListView of a folder iterating recursively. This is the from of the list.

- Folder 1

  - Fodler 1.1

    - File 1
    - File 2
  - Folder 1.2

    - Folder 1.2.1

      - File 1
- Folder 2

  - File 1
    etc..

If this is the structure of the folder recursivley i need to create an ExpandableListView in which **Folder 1**, **Folder 1.1**, **Folder 1.2**, **Folder 2**, etc.. are expandable and **File 1**, **File 2** etc are just listview. I need the logic to create such an ExpandableListView.

Comment: Expandable list view can have only one child. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html  
You can use simple list and create a file array and change the adapter as well  *File MainCategory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 
  MainCategory.mkdirs();
  File[] listOfFiles = MainCategory.listFiles();*

Comment: so its not possible with expandable list..??

Answer (score 3):

MultiLevelListView is an Open Source Android library providing view for displaying items grouped into levels and sub-levels. Levels hierarchy size is not limited. Any particular data model is not required, it fully depends on developer.

check : https://github.com/open-rnd/android-multi-level-listview.git

Comment: This should be comment